# Backspace character does not move the cursor back to the previous line in terminal

Tags: c, linux

I am using Ubuntu 12.10, while making a program i observed that the backspace character ('\b') can move the cursor one position back on the same line inside the terminal, but didn't worked when i wanted it to move back to the previous line?

How can i achieve this using C language?

Answer (score 2):

This is really a question about the behavior of your terminal, not C. I don't know any easy way to "backspace to the previous line" aside from "move up one line" followed by "move to end of line" or similar. On Linux, `man console_codes` will give you good documentation of standard terminal escapes. All relevant terminals are sufficiently similar that, if you just want to do cursor positioning and not fancy color stuff, you should just be able to hard-code the codes.

As Peter said, you could also use a higher-level library like ncurses if you prefer. Whether this makes sense depends a lot on the scope of what you're doing.

Comment: oh Will dig into this, btw do you have any good resource(s) on making interactive/colorful terminal based applications?

Comment: Also note that simply switching to a different terminal emulator may provide at least a temporary solution - some emulators don't backspace-to-previous line, some do, and some have options to control whether they do or not.

Answer (score 0):

the normal terminal is line-orientated, so you have to take a more complex path, like using the curses-library and do the semantics yourself